# Dependency injection issues after upgrade to Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, service, angular-services, angular-library

I have an Angular project that contains a web application and a library, both generated by the Angular CLI.

To explain my issue, I broke it down to make it as simple as possible. Assume that the library has two services, the first is a generic service that performs http calls:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class ApiService { 

    protected constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
        console.log(httpClient);
    }

}
```

The second service actually implements methods for the project, for example

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export abstract class NewsService extends ApiService { 

    /* THERE IS NO CONSTRUCTOR HERE! */

    getNews() { ... }

}
```

So until now (before Angular 8), I had no issues calling `getNews()` from the web application. Since Angular 8, I get an error that says `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. I found that the property `httpClient` remains undefined forever. Thus, `console.log` above in the `ApiService` prints `undefined`. Until Angular 7, the injection of the `HttpClient` class worked as expected.

Imagine now that I adjust the `NewsService` as follows:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export abstract class NewsService extends ApiService { 

    protected constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
        super(httpClient);
    }

    getNews() { ... }

}
```

Now, `httpClient` is not undefined anymore in the constructor of `ApiService`.

According to my understanding, this behavior is really weird. If I don't provide a constructor in the child class, it should use the parent constructor instead and thus behave the same. Since Angular 8, this is not the case anymore.

Do you know why this happened and if there is another way to fix this issue?

EDIT: I have to add one remark: The injection issue does NOT appear when I install the library through NPM in another project. It only appears when I directly use it in the same Angular project.

Comment: Did you try to add `providedIn: "root"` in your `ApiService`?

Comment: Did you register the ApiService in the providers array too?

Comment: @youri I tried it, but it didn't help. Also it should not be provided as abstract service class, I think.

Comment: @Okyo do I have to do that, when I add `providedIn: "root"`? I tried to provide it on the web application's `AppModule`, but that did not help. EDIT: In fact, I cannot provide it anyway because it's abstract.

Comment: The weird thing is that it _used_ to work without explicit call. I see nothing wrong to explicitly call `super()`

Comment: I have around 20 services, so I would need to implement duplicate code a lot. It is calming though that we know how to fix it. But, to be honest, I don't understand why it would be needed to explicitly call `super()` in the child's class constructor.

Comment: I added a remark at the end of the post, which might help to find the issue.

Comment: It should work. I just try an example and it is working as expected... How did you instanciate `NewsService` and call its methods?

Comment: I'm injecting `NewsService` into any component of the project, for example into the constructor of `HomeComponent`. As I have used `providedIn: "root"`, I do not provide it at the module level.

Comment: As it is working when importing your library, I think there is an error during your upgrade. Maybe an error in the `package.config` or a corrupted package. Try removing your package folder and clearing npm cache (`npm cache clean`) and then reinstall your packages.

Comment: @andreas also check [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30881) on Github.